# No such file found with semaphore.h and ucontext.h

Tags: c, semaphore, ucontext

I have my code here:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include "lib-ult.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <ucontext.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define FAILURE -1

typedef struct Node {
    ucontext_t* context;
    int priority;

    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
} Node;

int STACK_SIZE = 16384;

sem_t queueLock;

sem_t threadsLock;
```

And when I try to build the project I get `Error 1 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ucontext.h': No such file or directory` (and also for semaphore.h).

Why is this?  How do I fix it?  Does it have to do with the fact that I have a Windows machine?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you compile this source file?

Answer (score 2):

`ucontext.h` and `semaphore.h` are part of the `linux-headers` linux package. I don't think you'll be able to compile this application on Windows. Install a virtual machine with Linux and try to compile there.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `semaphore.h` and/or `ucontext.h` in `/path/to/dir`, you could add option `-I/path/to/dir` to `gcc` to fix this problem.

By the way, `semaphore.h` and `ucontex.h` are parts of Glibc, with a properly installed GNU Toolchain, `gcc` should be able to find them without any additional options.

Comment: -L is library path not include path (-1)